# Agregar columnas listview con sql server desde vb

Tags: vb.net

Buenas quisiera que me ayden estoy realizando un Listview que como defecto le puse estos valores en las columnas:

. Numero Credito

. Numero de Cuota

. Ultima Cuota

. Rubro

pero quiero que esos list view se incrementen el numero de columnas como tiene la base de datos en sus campos 
 Mi tabla se llama rubro tiene este unico campo:
 . Descripcion
 Pero dentro como registro tiene estos datos:
 . SEGUROS ASISTENCIA HOSPITALARIA
 . SEGURO DE DESGRAVAMEN

lo que yo quiero que en el list view figure con esas columnas de los registros de la base de datos como este:
. Numero Credito

. Numero de Cuota

. Ultima Cuota

. Rubro

. SEGUROS ASISTENCIA HOSPITALARIA

. SEGURO DE DESGRAVAMEN

este es mi codigo que realize pero si muestra pero se muestra como registros yo quiero como columnas este es mi codigo:

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
    Me.ListView1.GridLines = True
    conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=********\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=Credito;User ID=****;Password=*****")
    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
    strQ = "select top 5 Descripcion from credito..Rubro WHERE IdRubro NOT IN (41,42,44,45,1056,1057,1058,48,43) "
    cmd = New SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Rubros")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    ' adding the columns in ListView
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString())
    Next
    'Now adding the Items in Listview
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
        Next
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
        Me.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    Next
End Sub
```

Esta es con este codigo me sale el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres que los registros añadidos no sean celdas, sino columnas del mismo ListView, si entiendo bien?

Comment: @TwoDent muchas gracias por responder ya lo solucione :
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString())
            Next

Comment: brother, agrega tu respuesta y luego acéptala, así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) y ayudas a crecer a más desarolladores :D

Comment: por cierto, bienvenido al sitio :D

Comment: @Pierro SO te da la opción de responder tus preguntas, podrías revisar: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la Respuesta como crear columnas con sql server segun los registros.
Saludos.

```
 Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
        Me.ListView1.GridLines = True
        ListView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable
        Dim columnHeader1 As New ColumnHeader
        With columnHeader1
            .Text = "Numero de Credito"
            .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
            .Width = 146
        End With
        Dim columnHeader2 As New ColumnHeader
        With columnHeader2
            .Text = "Numero Cuota"
            .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            .Width = 142
        End With
        Dim columnHeader3 As New ColumnHeader
        With columnHeader3
            .Text = "Ultima Cuota"
            .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            .Width = 142
        End With

        conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.105.150\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=Credito;User ID=sa;Password=DBServ@14")
        Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
        strQ = "select top 2 Descripcion from credito..Rubro WHERE IdRubro NOT IN (41,42,44,45,1056,1057,1058,48,43) "
        cmd = New SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "Rubros")
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        ' adding the columns in ListView
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                Dim LSet = Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString())
                LSet.Width = 218
            Next

        Next

    End Sub
```